# Integrating under a curve in R

Tags: r, modeling, auc

I apologise if this is a duplicate; I've read answers to similar questions to no avail.

I'm trying to integrate under a curve, given a specific formula (below) for said integration.

[image]

As a toy example, here's some data:

```
Antia_Model <- function(t,y,p1){
  r <- p1[1]; k <- p1[2]; p <- p1[3]; o <- p1[4] 
  P <- y[1]; I <- y[2]
  dP = r*P - k*P*I
  dI = p*I*(P/(P + o))
  list(c(dP,dI))
}
r <- 0.25; k <- 0.01; p <- 1; o <- 1000 # Note that r can range btw 0.1 and 10 in this model
parms <- c(r, k, p, o)
P0 <- 1; I0 <- 1
N0 <- c(P0, I0)
TT <- seq(0.1, 50, 0.1)
results <- lsoda(N0, TT, Antia_Model, parms, verbose = FALSE)
P <- results[,2]; I <- results[,3]
```

As I understand it, I should be able to use the `auc()` function from the MESS package (can I just use the `integrate()` function? Unclear...), which should look something like this:

```
auc(P, TT, from = x1, to = x2, type = "spline")
```

Though I don't really understand how to use the "from" and "to" arguments, or how to incorporate "u" from the original integration formula...

Using the `integrate()` function seems more intuitive, but if I try:

```
u <- 1
integrand <- function(P) {u*P}
q <- integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
```

I get this error:

```
# Error in integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf) : 
  # the integral is probably divergent
```

As you can tell, I'm pretty lost, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Firstly, you have to define the function P: `P <- function(t) { ......}`.

Answer (score 0):

`integrand` is technically acceptable but right now, it's the identity function f(x) = x. The area under it from [0, inf) is infinite, i.e. divergent.

From the documentation of `integrate` the first argument is:

> an R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length. Returning a non-finite element will generate an error.

If instead you use a pulse function:

```r
pulse <- function(x) {ifelse(x < 5 & x >= 0, 1, 0)}

integrate(pulse, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
#> 5 with absolute error < 8.5e-05
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure what you're saying here, but I appreciate the detailed answer! I think I'm overthinking my question, so maybe I phrased it poorly. I think I figured out a pretty basic (but maybe slightly incomplete) fix.